# CreateDataPartition gave me Error: 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Tags: r

I got below error while I was trying to use CreateDataPartition() function from caret package.  Here y variable accepts vector and I'm passing a column from my data.frame. I hope it is in correct format. I still don't understand why it is giving me error.

My Code:

`bikeInTrain<-createDataPartition(y=bikeTrainRaw$datetime, p=0.7,list = FALSE)`

Error:

`Error in matrix(unlist(out), ncol = times) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'`

datetime column is of factor class. Should I change this to something else?
Let me know If I'm going wrong somewhere.